# Evaluate the triple integral bounded by a cylinder and planes

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate the triple integral $\displaystyle\iiint\limits_{W}z\,dx\,dy\,dz$ over the region $W$ which is bounded by the planes $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, $z=1$, and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ in the first octant.

I'm not sure if I got the bounds of integration right, but here is what I ended up with.

$x$: $0$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$

$y$: $0$ to $1$

$z$: $0$ to $1$

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Those bounds are correct, but you may find it easier to evaluate by converting to cylindrical coordinates, in which case, the bounds for each variable will be constant.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try.